# Which directory does marklogic deploys the application created with appbuilder

Tags: marklogic

I have created an application through Marklogic's application builder and hit the deploy button. I am trying to find the location or the path where Marklogic has deployed this application.Can someone help me  where Marklogic stores this application. I have installed Marklogic in c:\Marklogic

Thanks
shashi

Answer (score 4):

Application Builder creates a modules database for your application. This is just like the database for your content, in that it holds documents, but these documents are the XQuery, JavaScript, CSS, etc that make up your application. Take a look at the Admin UI on port 8001 and you'll see a -modules database named for your app.

When I work with App Builder, I like to [pull the application down to the file system](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2013/08/capturing-an-app-building-application-with-roxy/) and work with it there, but you can also edit the files in place using WebDAV.

Comment: :Yes I found the modules database and I got the generated application code css,js etc but xquery code is missing.I am using marklogic 7.I want to start customizing the app with the generated code especially the widgets.

Comment: The app-builder comprises of html/js/css on client-side. That is what you will find in the yourapp-modules database. The javascript interacts with MarkLogic through a REST api which is kind of built-in code. All widget stuff can be found in the javascript. Tweak search options XML to get more facets..